# Change language inside AlertDialog

Tags: android

I know that to support different language I have to add the `res/values-el` for example.

And I can't change by that all the buttons, TextViews etc.

But, if my app uses for example an AlertDialog, can I change the language of the title etc?

```
...
AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alt_bld.setMessage("Do you want to navigate to the saved position?")
.setCancelable(false)
.setPositiveButton("Navigate",
alert.setTitle("Navigation");    
...
```

Ok, if anyone wants to do that from a service he must use :

```
mContext.getString(R.string.Title)  //where mContext is the Context
```

instead of

```
getResources().getString(R.string.Title)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just need to get this title string from `strings.xml`. Do not hard-code strings in the code. [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html#UseString).

For example:

```
alert.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.navigation));
```

In `res/values/strings.xml` you define:

```
<string name="navigation">Navigation</string>
```

In `res/values-pl/strings.xml` (Polish language, for example):

```
<string name="navigation">Nawigacja</string>
```

Comment: :It worked fine as you said ,but I tried to use the same approach in a class which extends Service and it gives me NullPointer.It works only in Activities?Thanks!